# SQL in Play!Framework

Tags: playframework, hql

I have following SQL which run perfectly in SQL software (HeidiSQL)

```
SELECT gl2.documentNumber, gl2.debitAmount, gl2.creditAmount, 
 gl2.account, gl2.description FROM GeneralLedger AS gl1 
LEFT JOIN GeneralLedger AS gl2 
ON gl1.documentNumber = gl2.documentNumber 
WHERE gl1.account='911' AND gl2.account <> '911';
```

When put it into Play! controller, I use this:

```
     String queryPL = "SELECT gl2.documentNumber, gl2.debitAmount, gl2.creditAmount, "
            + "gl2.account, gl2.description FROM GeneralLedger AS gl1 "
            + "LEFT JOIN GeneralLedger AS gl2 "
            + "ON gl1.documentNumber = gl2.documentNumber "
            + "WHERE gl1.account='911' AND gl2.account <> '911'";
    Query query = JPA.em().createQuery(queryPL);
    List<Object[]> profitAndLoss = query.getResultList();
```

and received error:

> IllegalArgumentException occured :
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near
>   line 1, column 156 [SELECT gl2.documentNumber, gl2.debitAmount,
>   gl2.creditAmount, gl2.account, gl2.description FROM
>   models.GeneralLedger AS gl1 LEFT JOIN GeneralLedger AS gl2 ON
>   gl1.documentNumber = gl2.documentNumber WHERE gl1.account='911' AND
>   gl2.account <> '911']

I revised the HQL to

```
String queryPL = "SELECT gl2.documentNumber, gl2.debitAmount, gl2.creditAmount, "
                + "gl2.account, gl2.description FROM models.GeneralLedger AS gl1 "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN models.GeneralLedger AS gl2 "
                + "WITH gl1.documentNumber = gl2.documentNumber "
                + "WHERE gl1.account='911' AND gl2.account <> '911'";
        Query query = JPA.em().createQuery(queryPL);
        List<Object[]> profitAndLoss = query.getResultList();
```

and still receive an error:

> IllegalStateException occured : DOT node with no left-hand-side!

So how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to make a join between two entities in HQL, you need to have an association between these two entities. You can't make a join between two unrelated entities on any condition like you can in SQL. HQL and its join capabilities are described in great details in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins).

If you really need this type of join, use a native query.

Comment: Thank you. I just revised createQuery to CreateNativeQuery and some minor adjustment in query statement (using original one as in HeidiSQL and now it's work.